# Integrate News Updates in single app

Tags: java, android

I want create an app which integrates all the news updates at one place
Best example : NewsHunt

How can I communicate with different news feeds?
Is there any API's or Webservices available to get all the latest news updates from different news papers.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) format. nearly all news papers offer this service for free

also see here: [Web Syndication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_syndication), [Web feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed)